# Creating DNS packet with dnslib python

Tags: python, dns, packet-injection

Using dnslib with python 2.6

I created the following code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from dnslib import *
import sys

a = DNSRecord.question(sys.argv[1])

print a.pack()
```

when i try to do the following

```
a = DNSRecord.question(sys.argv[1],"A MX NS AAAA dnssec trace multiline")
```

dnslib.dns.DNSError: QTYPE: Invalid reverse lookup: [A MX NS AAAA dnssec trace multiline]

what i'd like to do is very simple

craft a packet with the following flags set in it and just pring the packed data

Is this possible using dnslib ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `trace` and `multiline` are "dig"-specific flags that affect dig's behaviour and not the wire protocol.
2. the `dnssec` flag sets the `DNSSEC OK` (aka `DO`) bit in an EDNS0 OPT RR that you would need to create and put in the "additional" section of the query.  However EDNS0 support in dnslib is very poor.
3. you can't put more than one `QTYPE` (i.e. `A MX NS AAAA`) in a single question - you'd need to ask a separate question for each.

Comment: do you suggest using scapy instead ?

Comment: well, that rather depends on exactly what your final goal is

Comment: just construct a raw dns packet .. to send it using hping / nemesis
with A query and DNSSEC flag set to 1